# Angular form value overwritten when editing a different value

Tags: angular, data-binding, angular-directive, angular-forms

I'm running into a weird issue with my form in `Angular 11`. I have a basic form configured, with a child component that is 2-way bound, like this:

```
  <form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="onSave()">
    <input type="text" formControlName="randomString" />
    <color-picker formControlName="primaryColor" [(color)]="primaryColor"></color-picker>
  </form>
```

When I select my color inside my color-picker component, it's correctly sending back the new hex value to the parent form above.

But as soon as I add/remove characters from the "randomString" input field, the value in the color-picker gets reverted back to what it was originally.

If I ONLY change the color picker value, and save, everything works fine. If I only change the "randomString" value and save, everything is fine. It's only when I change the color, then ALSO go change the randomString field, then the color-picker reverts.

I originally had this version of child-component:

```
<color-picker 
    id="primaryColor"
    title="Primary Color"
    [color]="form.value.primaryColor"
    (colorChange)="form.value.primaryColor=$event">
</color-picker>
```

But that also produced the same behavior, where as soon as randomString is edited, you can see the color-picker value change.

Any suggestions here?

Edit: here's the color-picker that I'm using, which is just the standard version:

```
        <input class="input-color-hide" id="color-input-{{title.replace(' ', '-')}}" type="color" [(value)]="color" (blur)="colorChanged($event)" />
```

Here's the form typescript:

```
this.form = this.builder.group({
  randomString: ['', Validators.required],
  primaryColor: ['', Validators.required]
});
```

And the colorChanged function, it just sends back the newly-selected color to the parent form:

```
  colorChanged(e): void {
    console.log('colorChanged...');
    
    this.color = e.target.value;
    this.colorChange.emit(this.color);
  }
```

Comment: Which color picker are you using ?

Comment: Please share your typescript

Comment: @akashvarshney updated question with the input[type="color"]

Comment: What does `colorChanged($event)` do? That will be called each time you pass from the color picker to the random string input.

Comment: @lbsn but I'm editing the "randomString" field, and as soon as that changes, then the primaryColor value reverts back to the original version. Do I have to register a bunch of "onChange" events so I can make sure my primaryColor doesn't get changed? That doesn't make sense, if so...

Comment: It's hard to tell what's happening there whithout seeing your whole code... Why do you need this two-ways binding on your picker: `[(color)]="primaryColor"` if it's registered as a form control? It would be helpful if you could put together a [working example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)